simple way on submit to turn text in a div into a value for a var
I have a div <div id="halfway">Text</div>
and when the submit button is pressed the text inside the HTML div will turn into a var
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //turn text in div to value inside var using PHP
    
    $coco='text inside halfway div';
}

As you can see not sure how to code the transfer part I know jJavaScript is get elementbyID by id and innerHTML but that's client side that the user will see... im lookin for somin that is ran in background,not seen or discreet and php is perfect if it can be done. Is there a way to do this?

I'm not completely sure what you are doing, but it sounds like you want to send the contents of a non-form control to the server, which is not something that a browser would do natively. If you want to send anything that's not a form value, you will need to tackle this with JavaScript, either through a hidden field or through AJAX or similar.

Please explain to us that your code should work with different client stations on your server

You need to do this with JavaScript in the browser. It will need to copy the DIV contents into a hidden form input. When a form is submitted, it only sends named inputs to the server, not div contents.

Your question's wording is really not clear - you should review it. But I think probably Chris and Barmar have guessed what you mean. Update the question to clarify what you mean or whether you have any outstanding questions still.
